# Laravel 4 - validator Column not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, validation

When attempting to use the unique validation rule, I'm receiving this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `empleados` where `cedula` = asd and `id` <> asd)
```

This is my migration up function:

```
        Schema::create('empleados', function($table){
            $table->string('cedula');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('apellido');
            $table->string('sexo');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('cedula');
        });
```

And this is my model:

```
<?php
    class Empleado extends Eloquent {
        protected $table = 'empleados';
        protected $primaryKey = 'cedula';
        public $errors;
        protected $fillable = array('cedula','nombre','apellido','sexo');


        public function isValid($data,$edit)
        {
            $rules = array(
                'cedula'     => 'required|unique:empleados',
                'nombre' => 'required|max:40',
                'apellido'  => 'required|max:40',
                'sexo' => 'required'
            );

            if($edit){
                $rules['cedula'] .= ',cedula,' . $this->getKey();
            }

            (...)
```

I think that It's a bug with the "unique" validation rule because I don't know why laravel are using a column named 'id' when I never define that.

Comment: Not related to the issue, but what's `$table->create();` ?

Comment: Ups. I did not notice that. This table was made by a friend. It is already fixed. Thank you.

Comment: The primary key should NEVER be fillable!

Comment: @jah you are right. It was a design error. Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change this:

```
'cedula'     => 'required|unique:empleados',
```

to:

```
'cedula'     => 'required|unique:empleados,cedula',
```

and later, when editing, just add the value to ignore

```
if($edit){
    $rules['cedula'] .= ',' . $this->getKey() . ',cedula';
}
```

That's because Laravel does this:

1. Check that value `foo` is unique for column `cedula`
2. but ignore row with value `bar`

Now, if you don't specify which column should be checked against `bar` then Laravel will take `id` as default. To override that, just pass that column as 4th param of `unique`

Comment: What you mean by that?

Comment: I did what you recommended, but the error still appears

Comment: Dude, It's works. Thank you very much =) Now, you know why happens this?

Comment: added explanation to the answer. Also, 1st part is not necessary in your case, it would be required if the key was not `cedula` (col name)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I figured it was something like this. ( Cédula is the name that we give to the identity document in Venezuela ).

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
// Set Primary to null
protected $primaryKey = null;

// Set increment to false
public $incrementing = false;
```

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#37-42

Comment: Where do I add that? In my model or in the eloquent/model.php?